# Ruby remove everything except some characters?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

How can I remove from a string all characters except white spaces, numbers, and some others?
Something like this:

```
oneLine.gsub(/[^ULDR0-9\<\>\s]/i,'')
```

I need only: `0-9 l d u r < > <space>`

Also, is there a good document about the use of regex in Ruby, like a list of special characters with examples?

Comment: http://rubular.com should be just what you are looking for.

Comment: @Michael: I don't think this is helpful, because the regex already works. What doesn't work as expected is how it's applied here.

Comment: I was referring to the last sentence. Rubular has a nice concise explanation of Ruby's regular expressions at the bottom, plus a chance to try them out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regex you have is already working correctly. However, you do need to assign the result back to the string you're operating on. Otherwise, you're not changing the string (`.gsub()` does not modify the string in-place).

You can improve the regex a bit by adding a '+' quantifier (so consecutive characters can be replaced in one go). Also, you don't need to escape angle brackets:

```
oneLine = oneLine.gsub(/[^ULDR0-9<>\s]+/i, '')
```

A good resource with special consideration of Ruby regexes is the [Regular Expressions Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596520694.do) by Jan Goyvaerts and Steven Levithan. A good online tutorial by the same author is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html).

Answer (score 5):

Good old `String#delete` does this without a regular expression. The `^` means 'NOT'.

```
str = "12eldabc8urp pp"
p str.delete('^0-9ldur<> ') #=> "12ld8ur "
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness: you don't need a regular expression for this particular task, this can be done using [simple string manipulation](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr):

```
irb(main):005:0> "asdasd123".tr('^ULDRuldr0-9<>\t\r\n ', '')
=> "dd123"
```

There's also the `tr!` method if you want to replace the old value:

```
irb(main):009:0> oneLine = 'UasdL asd 123'
irb(main):010:0> oneLine.tr!('^ULDRuldr0-9<>\t\r\n ', '')
irb(main):011:0> oneLine
=> "UdL d 123"
```

This should be a bit faster as well (but performance shouldn't be a big concern in Ruby :)

Comment: The `d` should remain in the string. Is there a way to make `.tr()` case-insensitive?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Yes, I just noticed that.. I don't think there's a builtin way except for hardcoding both versions of the character.

Comment: "but performance shouldn't be a big concern in Ruby" - just curious why you'd say that? is it because typically ruby isnt used in high performance apps?

Comment: @Steven: In any programming language, between different solutions to the same problem, I'd usually choose the simplest rather than the most performant, *unless* I have proven that this piece of code is actually a bottleneck in my application and really needs to be optimized. This is especially true for dynamic languages like Ruby, which are specifically designed to be "productive" and concise to write.

Comment: niklas, understandable and i agree. i was just wanting to clarify if ruby was just synonymous with slower performance.

Comment: Trust me this, aplication is not about performance, I have lots of another awful stuff in my code. It's just easy project to school, do it fast as possible. If you wanna see: [link](https://github.com/zajca/Projekt_ADV_ALG/blob/master/project.rb)